# What are the applications of holomorphic families of operators?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, geometry, partial-differential-equations, soft-question

I ma studying something about operators theory and I often find the term of “holomorphic family of operators”. My question is: why holomorphic families of operators are important? What are they applications?

I look for some references (I have already read the paper by Kato about this argument) that could tell me something more about their utility and applications.

I hope anyone could help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One application is in scattering theory (which can be applied to lots of fields, such as quantum mechanics and general relativity). The relevant theorem is the analytic Fredholm theorem.

The analytic Fredholm theorem (rather, a simpler version of it) tells you that if you have a family of Fredholm operators which are holomorphic (over an open, connected set), and the family is invertible at a point, then the family of inverse operators form a meromorphic family, and the poles have finite rank.

This theorem is used to obtain meromorphic continuations of resolvents in PDE theory. The study of the resolvent is of fundamental importance in scattering theory. In particular, poles of the meromorphic continuation of the resolvent are called *resonances*, which carry important information about decay rates of solutions. This is a very expansive and deep subject, and I won't do it justice without writing an essay. See [http://math.mit.edu/~dyatlov/res/res_final.pdf](http://math.mit.edu/%7Edyatlov/res/res_final.pdf) for more.